# What is the MySql regex equivalent for 

Tags: mysql, regex

In .Net, I use `^[BG]\d(0-9)4$` for a `Regex.IsMatch ( ... )` comparison. I am looking for the equivalent regex in MySql. Any help?

**EDIT**
corrected the regex used in .Net - it should only allow 'b', 'B', 'g', or 'G' at the beginning.

allowed samples:
 - b1234
 - B2254
 - g5534
 - G1122

disallowed:
 - any letter besides b, B, g, G
 - fewer than 4 digits following b/B/g/G
 - greater than 4 digits following b/B/g/G

Comment: Do you really want to match B or G, then one digit, then the literal text `0-94`?

Comment: You probably want either \d{4} or [0-9]{4}, based on your edits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't your current regex reject all examples? If they're anyhting to go by you want:

```
^[BG][0-9]{4}$`
```

Which should work in your app and MySQL.

Comment: The .Net regex I have been using was provided for me a while back - and I would have to go dig to make sure I provided the correct format. Nonetheless, this works ...

Answer (score 0):

**Edited for updated expression and examples in question.**

Try:

```
REGEXP '^[BG]\d{4}$'
```

*Disclaimer: I'm not where I have access to a MySQL server now, so that answer is based on the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), not actually typing it in and trying it.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to match but following queries match fine for me:

```
SELECT 'B544' REGEXP '^[B,G][0-9][0-9]4$';
SELECT ',544' REGEXP '^[B,G][0-9][0-9]4$';
SELECT 'G544' REGEXP '^[B-G][0-9][0-9]4$';
```

#### EIDT:

Based on your comments you should use regex `'^[BG][0-9]{4}$'` here are examples:

```
-- doesn't match
SELECT 'a1234' REGEXP '^[BG][0-9]{4}$';
SELECT 'B12345' REGEXP '^[BG][0-9]{4}$';
SELECT 'G123' REGEXP '^[BG][0-9]{4}$';

-- matches
SELECT 'B1234' REGEXP '^[BG][0-9]{4}$';
SELECT 'G1122' REGEXP '^[BG][0-9]{4}$';
```

Comment: Edited my answer as per your comments and edited question, please check.